# Add custom flow type for object method

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I would like refacto' my method by adding `flow type`. My actual code :

```
const apiActions = {
  registerThroughApi: async (
    state: Object,
    action: Function,
    formData: Object
  ): Object => {
    return state;
  }
};
```

Is it possible to add `flow type` ?

```
type Form = {
  state: Object,
  action: Function,
  formData: Object
}

const apiActions = {
  registerThroughApi: async (state, action, formData)<Form>: Object => {
    return state;
  }
};
```

But this code don't work :D

Anyone know if it's possible ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

not sure I'm understanding exactly, but what about something like this

```
// @flow

const apiActions = {
  registerThroughApi: async (state: Object, action: Function, formData: Object): Object => {
    return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: It's not possible to add function parameters on `type` Object ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.